# cx_freeze returning invalid syntax with sympy

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, sympy

I am trying to convert python code to a windows .exe using cx_freeze. When I run the setup.py using the command line it runs as usual and then just returns invalid syntax. The program uses the tkinter module as well as sympy and I believe it is the latter causing the problem. Any solutions will be much appreciated. Below is the last part of the process before it stops.

```
deferredImports, namespace = namespace)

  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 338, in _Intern
alImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py", line 366, in _LoadMo
dule
    module.code = compile(codeString, path, "exec")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\sympy\mpmath\libmp\exec_py2.py", line 2
    exec string in globals, locals
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you show the error you get?

Comment: Does your code that uses `sympy` work on Python 3? If it does then something (probably `cx_freeze`) tries to import a module that is not used on Python 3 (`exec_py2`) and that contains invalid for Python 3 syntax (`exec()` is a function in Python 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compatibility for exec in SymPy (actually mpmath, which is included with SymPy) uses a file that is only run in Python 2 that is invalid syntax in Python 3 and a file that is only run in Python 3 that is invalid syntax in Python 2. You can safely ignore the one on the other. If cx_freeze refuses to skip this file, you can safely delete it.

Comment: Thanks, managed to make the exe but it closes as soon as I open it.

Comment: @Beamister: run it from a command prompt rather than double clicking - that closing immediately usually means it's exiting with an error that you don't get time to read.

Comment: @asmeurer: mpmath has actually [got rid of those files now](https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/mpmath/commit/fd2e8dcccd375cca0edbc392bafdf2fe0ebce60b#diff-2) - any plans to update it in sympy?

Comment: Yes, I plan to do so by the next version.

Comment: It is returning the followinr error: sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat

Comment: That sounds like a new problem. You should ask a new question for it.